# MLFlow Search Runs Order by Metrics

Tags: mlflow

I am attempting to use the MlFlow client to order my runs by a specific metric (test_rmse). However, the order_by argument is not recognizing the metric, and returning blank results. I think it has something to do with the nested results of the search_runs function...

Working example:

```
runs = mlflow_client.search_runs(experiment_ids = experiment_ids, order_by=["info.end_time"])
```

Not working example:

```
runs = mlflow_client.search_runs(experiment_ids = experiment_ids, order_by=["metrics.test_rmse"])
```

The **not** working example follows the documentation linked below to a T.
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html

I have tried many different syntaxes to get to the test_rmse metric including:
"data.metrics.test_rmse", "metrics.'test_rmse'", "data.metrics.'test_rmse'", "metrics['test_rmse'], data.metrics.['test_rmse']", "metrics[test_rmse], data.metrics.[test_rmse]"

and none have worked.

Here is an example of a 'Run' element that is returned if there is no order_by:

````
<Run: data=<RunData: metrics={'test_mape': 20.545290384026003,
 'test_rmse': 7722.505535457056,
 'training_mae': 1317.665098010665,
 'training_mse': 2600325.7268625204,
 'training_r2_score': 0.9597774286238024,
 'training_rmse': 1612.5525501088391,
 'training_score': 0.9597774286238023}, params={'alpha': '0.9',
 'criterion': 'friedman_mse',
 'init': 'None',
 'learning_rate': '0.1',
 'loss': 'ls',
 'max_depth': '3',
 'max_features': 'None',
 'max_leaf_nodes': 'None',
 'min_impurity_decrease': '0.0',
 'min_impurity_split': 'None',
 'min_samples_leaf': '1',
 'min_samples_split': '2',
 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': '0.0',
 'n_estimators': '100',
 'n_iter_no_change': 'None',
 'presort': 'auto',
 'random_state': '12',
 'subsample': '1.0',
 'tol': '0.0001',
 'validation_fraction': '0.1',
 'verbose': '0',
 'warm_start': 'False'}, tags={'brand': 'dominicks',
 'estimator_class': 'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting.GradientBoostingRegressor',
 'estimator_name': 'GradientBoostingRegressor',
 'mlflow.parentRunId': '2bccc81e-a97c-4704-bb06-e889701172e2',
 'mlflow.rootRunId': 'red_planet_0b4kbtckls',
 'mlflow.runName': 'plum_neck_0svr7057',
 'mlflow.user': 'Zack Soenen',
 'store': '1000'}>, info=<RunInfo: artifact_uri='', end_time=1704397763872, experiment_id='e6a75da7-2df2-4211-8f15-b4e8d9ee8e23', lifecycle_stage='active', run_id='65dcfeea-aa57-4c83-80a4-6b1ee9ac8c9c', run_name='plum_neck_0svr7057', run_uuid='65dcfeea-aa57-4c83-80a4-6b1ee9ac8c9c', start_time=1704397755468, status='FINISHED'>```
````

Comment: Update: I am using the python SDK. 
mlflow_client = mlflow.MlflowClient()

Comment: Please do **not** use the comment space for adding info; edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided as the `"Not working example"` is actually correct in terms of syntax. The issue might be related to how the metric is logged during the runs.

Here are a few things to check:

1. Metric Logging: Make sure that you are logging the "test_rmse" metric correctly during your MLflow runs. Ensure that the metric is being logged with the correct key.

Example:

```bash
mlflow.log_metric("test_rmse", your_test_rmse_value)
```

2. Metric Availability: Confirm that the "test_rmse" metric is available for all the runs you are trying to order. If a run didn't log this metric, it might not be included in the ordering.
3. MLflow Version: Ensure that you are using a version of MLflow that supports ordering by metrics. Some features may have been introduced or changed in different MLflow versions.

Comment: The metric is definitely available, but it is double nested in the output (data --> metrics ---> test_rmse)   
  
<Run: data=<RunData: metrics={'test_mape': 20.545290384026003,
 'test_rmse': 7722.505535457056...

Comment: I am using mlflow version 1.30.1